# Indexing a subset of an adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, adjacency-matrix

I have a **200 x 200** adjacency matrix called **M**. This is the connection strength for 200 nodes (the nodes are numbered 1 to 200 and organized in ascending order in M - i.e., M(23,45) is the connection strength of node 23 and 45). Out of these 200 nodes, I'm interested in three subsets of nodes.

```
subset1 = [2,34,36,42,69,102,187];
subset2 = [5,11,28,89,107,199];
subset3 = [7,55,60,188];
```

Using **M**, I would like to conduct the following operations:

1. Average of the connection strength *within* **subset1**, **subset2**, and **subset3**, separately. For instance, for subset1, that would be the mean connection of all possible pairs of nodes 2, 34, 26,..., 187.
2. Find the connection strength *between* **subset1**, **subset2**, and **subset3**. This would be the average of connection strength between all pairs of node spanning all possible pairs of the three subsets (average of connection between subset1 & subset2, subset2 & subset3, and subset1 & subset3). Do note that this between connection does not equate putting all the nodes from three subsets into a single matrix (e.g., connection between two subsets is the mean connection of each node in one subset with every node in *the other* subset).

What I've tried so far was indexing **M** using a for loop. It was bulky, especially when I have a large number of nodes in each subset. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
M1 = M(subset1, subset1);
ind = triu(true(size(M1)), 1); % upper triangle
M1_avg = mean(M1(ind));
```

I will leave M2_avg and M1_M2_avg to you.

Comment: Thank you, Xiangrui Li. The within average works perfectly. I resorted to the for loop for my average between.